# Is there something wrong with plnkr.co's angular CDN?

Tags: angularjs

Is there something wrong with the way plnkr.co references angular?

This isn't working: http://plnkr.co/edit/TcHDbxSZTWNTNG9KLcM0?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="2.0.0-alpha.22" src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.22/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app>
   <input type="text" ng-model="item1"/>
   <input type="text" ng-model="item2"/>
   <br>
   Total: {{2+2}}
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can see it on the developer tools. https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.22/angular.js returns 404.

Comment: Interesting.  Major screw up on their part.

Comment: not hard to look for a good url on https://code.angularjs.org/

Comment: its working bro, the problem is your using `angular 2.0` its so much different than the `angular 1.x` if you change it to `angular 1.x` its will work :)

Comment: Right.  I was asking specifically about the default CDN plnkr.co drops in.

Comment: There is no `their` about plunker... it is one guy, who is an accountant during the day full time

Comment: Seems that all Angular2 package links are broken, as they are all of the form `https://code.angularjs.org/.../angular.js` when it should be `angular2.js` instead (cheked the 3 versions present, alpha-19, alpha-20 and alpha-22, and they all follow this naming convention - at least at this point). So, for now, simply edit your script src to have `angular2.js` as the file name, and you'll no longer have problems with angular2 not loading.